# Empty graphics when using Hue in a Raster?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Why does the following code

```
Graphics[Raster[{{Hue[1], Hue[1/3]}, {Hue[2/3], Hue[1/6]}}]]
```

not produce any output? In Mathematica < 6 RasterArray was able to handle this and produced the same output as

```
Graphics[Raster[{{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}}]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of `Raster` indicates that its arguments are not graphics directives (e.g. Hue, RGBColor) but rather numbers - a gray level (single number), RGB values (three numbers), RGBalpha values (four numbers), or gray-alpha values (two numbers). However, it provides the ability to instead specify the color function yourself, for example:

```
Graphics[Raster[{{0, 0.2, 0.4}, {0.6, 0.8, 1}}, ColorFunction -> Hue]]
```

(straight from the documentation for v6)